# Complex REGEX to Block Porn based on pre-defined text strings

Tags: regex

I am looking for the perfect 1 line regex pattern to block a huge list of porn star names using my content blocking software.

The software is fully regex-compliant, and will accept any well-written regex.

As an example, here is a line of those I currently use - the lines are identical somehow where the first blocks everything starting with, and the second blocks everything ending with my list of predefined words.

```
(\b(cohf|cock(s)?|cum(s)?|cutie(s)?|creamy(-)?pie(s)?))(-)?\w+\b
\w+(-)?((cam(s)?|cohf|cock(s)?|cum(s)?|cutie(s)?|creamy(-)?pie(s)?)\b)
```

Now, I have a list that looks like:

```
**pornstar1 name**
pornstar2 name
pornstar3 name
some-other name-here
```

I would like the offered regex to block ANY/ALL URL's, where the two parts of the name appear - Examples:

- www.alink-to-**pornstar1**.com <-- not blocked (only a part pf the
  name is here)
- www.alink-to-**pornstar1-name**.com <-- blocked (has
  the two parts)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: What programming language? Assembly code? :))

Comment: The programming language is absolutely irrelevant. Consider it whatever you want, REGEX is universal you know ;)

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant - regex is not universal, there are many different implementations. Examples: BRE, ERE, Emacs, and PCRE. Your example would only work with PCRE (out of the listed examples).

Comment: Thank you jordanm.. ok i agree, but what I meant to say is that the "major logic" in writing regex is universal.. do not get me wrong please. And yes, PCRE is what i am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take url and remove all `[^a-zA-Z]` *- replace them by empty string*
2. Take list of all not allowed words or phrases and do same as (1)
3. With such list now join all keywords with `|` character to one regex string
4. Check if this regex match url you modified at (1)

Having variables `url` and `list`, one-line jQuery solution would be:

```
url.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'').match(new RegExp("("+$.map(list,function(e){return e.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'');}).join('|')+")"))!=null
```

with result being `true` if `url` contains some of the restricted words or phrases from the `list`.

Comment: Thanks friend, I know the logic you described. I was checking/asking if there is a regex-way to make sure BOTH parts of the string exist in a given string.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant - When some restricted phrase contains more words, removing space between them you get one keyword that is then checked for match. That is the most effective way, I believe. **I have updated my answer with code.** Good luck!